# merging some differences but not all

Tags: git

```
git version 1.7.1
```

I have create 2 branches i.e. branch1 and branch2.

I have been developing on branch1 and branch2. So both branches are different now.

However, I want to merge branch1 into branch2. But what I am not sure about is that I only want to merge some code changes. I have written some functions in branch1 and I just want to merge those functions and nothing else.

Is that possible using git?

Comment: cherry-pick? http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cherry-pick` command to get individual commits from one branch.Then use the method shown here to split the commit into individual commits.

Use the `git rebase -i` to get the original commit to edit it.
Then `git reset HEAD^` to selectively revert changes, 
Then `git commit` to commit that bit as a new commit in the history.

or

using
git `add --patch` or possibly git `add --interactive` which allows you to add just parts of a hunk, if you want to split different changes to an individual file

i hope its helps to you

Answer (score 2):

Git reasons in term of snapshot of codes, representing the full content of the *all* project, commits after commits.

That means you can easily [cherry-pick](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) one or several commits from one branch to another (as suggested by [KingCrunch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421223/kingcrunch) in the comments)

But you cannot merge some files (and not others) within one commit.
You can try a `rebase --interactive branch1~x` in order to edit the last x commits with the relevant changes, splitting those commits into 2:

- one with common changes,
- the other with the changes you want to merge.

Then you can reorder those second sets of commits, and rebase them or cheery-pick them on top of `branch2`.

Comment: Well, you *could* do a partial merge (`merge --no-commit`, and unstage some changes), but it's a spectacularly bad idea, since as far as Git's concerned, it's a true merge. The best thing, of course, is to avoid having to ask this question - develop separate things on separate branches. The interactive rebase could help get you there, though!

Comment: @Jefromi: btw, did you see the comments of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524731/git-ignoring-gitattributes-pattern/5525195#5525195 ? (or do you want me to include said comments in my answer?)