# git archive : export-ignore, ignoring directories

Tags: git, gitattributes, git-archive

I have a git repository with this `.gitattributes`:

```
my_script.py export-subst
Makefile export-ignore
README.md export-ignore
.gitattributes export-ignore
.gitignore export-ignore
hooks/ export-ignore
tests/ export-ignore
*.pyc export-ignore
```

but when I make:

```
git archive HEAD | tar -x -C ../archive_dir
```

in the `archive_dir` directory, I get the directories `hooks` and `tests`:

```
 ls ../archive_dir/
 hooks/  my_script.py tests/
```

Why?

My git version is 1.7.9.

Comment: @twalberg git version : 1.7.9

Comment: @twalberg , git export-ignore other files, only have problems with the directories

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I removed the `/` in the directories, this fixed the problem

```
my_script.py export-subst
Makefile export-ignore
README.md export-ignore
.gitattributes export-ignore
.gitignore export-ignore
hooks export-ignore
tests export-ignore
*.pyc export-ignore
```

I find the solution in a answer to a similar question: [git ignoring .gitattributes pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524731/git-ignoring-gitattributes-pattern#answer-12060372)

Comment: Please note that you exclude all `hooks` folder down the tree. To exclude only the one in the root, prepend it with slash: `/hooks`.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, possible since Git 2.2+ (November 2014) is to **filter the path** you want to include in the archive.

See [commit ed22b41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed22b4173bd8d6dbce6236480bd30a63dd54834e) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds):

### `archive`: support filtering paths with glob

> This patch fixes two problems with using :`(glob)` (or even "`*.c`" without "`:(glob)`").

> The first one is we forgot to turn on the 'recursive' flag in `struct pathspec`. Without that, `tree_entry_interesting()` will not mark potential directories "interesting" so that it can confirm whether those directories have anything matching the pathspec.

> The marking directories interesting has a side effect that we need to walk inside a directory to realize that there's nothing interested in there. By that time, '`archive`' code has already written the (empty) directory down.
> That means lots of empty directories in the result archive.

> This problem is fixed by lazily writing directories down when we know they are actually needed. There is a theoretical bug in this implementation: we can't write empty trees/directories that match that pathspec.

> `path_exists()` is also made stricter in order to detect non-matching pathspec because when this 'recursive' flag is on, we most likely match some directories. The easiest way is not consider any directories "matched".

Examples:

```
git archive -v HEAD -- ":(glob)**/sh"

git archive -o docs.zip v2.2.0 'Documentation/*.html'
```

---

Note (7 years later), this same command is being refactored with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021)
See [commit 4795748](https://github.com/git/git/commit/47957485b3b731a7860e0554d2bd12c0dce1c75a), [commit 6c9fc42](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c9fc42e9f1bf27a3830ef594b7f5f9147af8361), [commit 7367d88](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7367d88261e5df7b1458cc02217f0e302bc2e127), [commit 9614ad3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9614ad3ce09937f3124db09cc8c6dd2777a15515), [commit fcc7c12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fcc7c12f1139d5b1fd657a4e89425f07dbc78d8a), [commit eefadd1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eefadd18e10fc0c4c808faa8ee077f375f28050c), [commit 8de7821](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8de78218c53480ded696c751f922b0622697a8b0), [commit dcc0a86](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dcc0a86f2f2f036b3a379f41a4b754f8bb73ed6b) (20 Mar 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ad16f74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad16f748f22c82d096664f15f1a1c7fcc361cfe3), 30 Mar 2021)</sup>

For example, referencing the commit mentioned above:

> ### [`archive`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7367d88261e5df7b1458cc02217f0e302bc2e127): stop passing "stage" through `read_tree_recursive()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> The "`stage`" variable being passed around in the archive code has only ever been an elaborate way to hardcode the value "0".
>
> This code was added in its original form in [e4fbbfe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4fbbfe9eccd37c0f9c060eac181ce05988db76c) ("Add `git-zip-tree`", 2006-08-26, Git v1.4.3-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4fbbfe9eccd37c0f9c060eac181ce05988db76c)), at which point a hardcoded "0" would be passed down through `read_tree_recursive()` to `write_zip_entry()`.
>
> It was then diligently added to the "`struct directory`" in [ed22b41](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed22b4173bd8d6dbce6236480bd30a63dd54834e) ("`archive`: support filtering paths with glob", 2014-09-21, Git v2.2.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2c45f5b961b3b5d894fb723d2031e8ff41cadf7)), but we were still not doing anything except passing it around as-is.
>
> Let's stop doing that in the code internal to [`archive.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7367d88261e5df7b1458cc02217f0e302bc2e127/archive.c), we'll still feed "0" to `read_tree_recursive()` itself, but won't use it.